# Add Android Gradle plugin as a runtime dependency

Tags: android, plugins, gradle, dependencies, runtime

I'm writing a Gradle plugin for Android, which uses new [Transform API](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api). Unfortunately, I faced a problem with adding Android plugin as a dependency to my plugin. A simplified Gradle configuration of my plugin looks like this:

**plugin/build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: "groovy"

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    compile "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta2"
}
```

And that's a simplified configuration of an application project that uses my Gradle plugin:

**application/build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta2"
        classpath "my-plugin:my-plugin:1.0.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "my-plugin"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.myapplication'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName version
    }
}
```

With this configuration everything works fine but I also want my plugin to work properly with projects that use previous versions of Android plugin. So I tried to change Android plugin version in my application's configuration file:

**application/build.gradle (with Android plugin 1.3.1)**:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1"
        classpath "my-plugin:my-plugin:1.0.0"
    }
}

/* Everything else is the same. */
```

But in this case Android plugin `1.4.0-beta2` is still used. I believe it happens because when Gradle resolves classpath dependencies, it prefers `1.4.0-beta2` over `1.3.1` so the whole project starts using version `1.4.0-beta2` of Android plugin.

I've also tried to add Android plugin as a `runtime` dependency but after making this change my plugin stops compiling because of 'unable to resolve' errors like this one:

```
Unable to resolve class com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant @ line 19, column 1.
import com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant
```

Is there a way to build my plugin against the latest version of Android plugin but at runtime use a version of Android plugin provided by the build environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve this problem by manually adding a `provided` scope. Here's a good article about adding `provided` scope to Gradle: http://www.sinking.in/blog/provided-scope-in-gradle/. Unfortunately, it doesn't explain how to make the `maven-publish` plugin handle the `provided` scope. So I'm going to explain how it can be done.

In my project I have a small plugin in `buildSrc` that is responsible for publishing to Maven. I added all the `provided`-related code to this plugin but it can be added to a `build.gradle` file.

The plugin skeleton looks like this:

```
class PublishPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    private static final PROVIDED_CONFIGURATION_NAME = "provided"

    private Project project

    @Override
    void apply(final Project project) {
        project.apply plugin: 'java'
        project.apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
        project.apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
        project.apply plugin: 'idea'

        addProvidedConfiguration()
        configureIdeaModule()

        project.afterEvaluate {
            modifyPomDependencyScopes()
        }
    }
```

Then we create a `provided` scope. Dependencies added with this scope can be used during compilation. In a generated `pom.xml` file these dependencies will have `provided` scope.

```
    private void addProvidedConfiguration() {
        final Configuration provided =
                addConfiguration(project.configurations,
                        PROVIDED_CONFIGURATION_NAME)
        final Javadoc javadoc =
                project.tasks.getByName(JavaPlugin.JAVADOC_TASK_NAME) as Javadoc
        javadoc.classpath = javadoc.classpath.plus(provided)
    }

    private static Configuration addConfiguration(
           final ConfigurationContainer configurations, final String name) {
        final Configuration compile =
                configurations.getByName(JavaPlugin.COMPILE_CONFIGURATION_NAME)
        final Configuration configuration = configurations.create(name)

        compile.extendsFrom(configuration)
        configuration.visible = false
        configuration.transitive = false

        configuration.allDependencies.all { final dependency ->
            configurations.default.exclude(
                    group: dependency.group, module: dependency.name)
        }

        return configuration
    }
```

I use IntelliJ IDEA so I need to make it 'understand' the `provided` scope. You have to do the same with Eclipse if you use it.

```
    private void configureIdeaModule() {
        project.idea.module {
            scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [project.configurations.provided]
        }
    }
```

And finally we need to change scopes in the generated `pom.xml` file. By default Gradle sets scopes for all dependencies to `runtime`. And the following code changes them to `compile` or `provided` if necessary.

```
    private void modifyPomDependencyScopes() {
        modifyPomDependencyScope(JavaPlugin.COMPILE_CONFIGURATION_NAME)
        modifyPomDependencyScope(PROVIDED_CONFIGURATION_NAME)
    }

    private void modifyPomDependencyScope(final String scope) {
        project.publishing.publications.all {
            pom.withXml {
                final DependencySet dependencies =
                        project.configurations.getByName(scope).allDependencies
                asNode().dependencies.'*'.findAll() {
                    dependencies.find { it.name == node.artifactId.text()
                }.each { it.scope*.value = scope }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. Then you just need to apply this plugin to a project that needs to be published to Maven and change a dependency type from `compile` to `provided`:

```
apply plugin: "groovy"
apply plugin: "my-publish-plugin"

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    provided "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta2"
}
```

Comment: How o specify version when declaring plugin in base plugin
like we do in gradle `id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.7.0-1.0.6"`